# Can`t Access Post Page After Migration

Tags: posts, migration

my Issue is, I move my website from local host to server(live) using **wp-all in one Migration** Plugin, after I successfully imported the site everything works fine, but when I visit the main Post page or any other specific post, it shows me this error

**There has been a critical error on this website.
Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.**

and the website turn responsive to tablet, it looks like I use the developer tool and make it responsive to tablet,
**What I have try**
Changing theme
Deactivating some plugins
I add this line to wp-config *define('WP_DEBUG', true);*
More over
All other pages are working fine only post page is the one i cant access, and
the site is working fine at the local host. Thank You

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate all your plugins and themes

- reactivate the theme and the required plugins of the theme; check if you have no bugs
- if no errors reactivate the other plugins one by one and check if there are no errors.

You can also follow this https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-find-and-access-wordpress-error-logs-step-by-step/ and share your logs

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I deactivate them all but the post page shows 404 error. and if i deactivate only the theme editor plugin it`s (colibri page builder) it still shows 404. but if i deactivate any other plugin it will not show that 404 error only this There has been a critical error on this website.

Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.

Comment: This is the log after I enable the debug mode.

Comment: sorry i cant past the log completely but please visit the site here  https://hedi.sadeeqtech.com.ng/news-2/

Comment: Without knowing what error is being logged no one can help you.

Comment: It is okay i now solved the error by removing the plugin that cause the issue. Thank you your answer helps a lot

Comment: @AbubakarAbdurrahman top, please make this question as solved.